# Spark - Single column to columns of X classes

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

Currently, I have a dataframe of a single column that looks like this

```
 color
 -----
 green
 blue
 green
 red
 yellow
 red
 orange
```

And so on...(30 different colors).

From that column, I would like to convert it to a DataFrame similar to this

```
green blue red yellow orange purple ... more colors
  1     0   0     0     0       0
  0     1   0     0     0       0
  1     0   0     0     0       0
  0     0   1     0     0       0
  0     0   0     1     0       0
  0     0   1     0     0       0
  0     0   0     0     1       0
```

A DataFrame that has every variable set to 0, except for the color that is on the same index of the original column.

So far, I have tried different functions and solution and none of them works (and the code looks really messy). I was wondering if there is an "easy" or simple way to do this, or I should use another library like Pandas (I'm using Python). If you know R, then what I want is the `table` function.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import when, lit, col

colors = df.select("color").distinct().map(lambda x: x[0]).collect()
cols = (
    when(col("color") == lit(color), 1).otherwise(0).alias(color)
    for color in colors
)

df.select(*cols)
```

If you're looking for another solution similar to R `table` you may want to take a look at the [`crosstab`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.crosstab) and [`cube`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.cube).

**Note**

When number of levels is large creating a dense data frame becomes rather inefficient. In such a case you should consider using a sparse vector:

```
from pyspark.sql import Row
from pyspark.mllib.linalg import Vectors
from pyspark.ml.feature import StringIndexer

def toVector(n): 
    def _toVector(i):
        return Row("vec")(Vectors.sparse(n, {i: 1.0}))
    return _toVector

indexer = StringIndexer(inputCol="color", outputCol="colorIdx")
indexed = indexer.fit(df).transform(df)
n = indexed.select("colorIdx").distinct().count()

vectorized = indexed.select("colorIdx").map(toVector(n)).toDF()
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I tried your solution, and unfortunately is not working properly.

The output is a dataframe where each column has the same name ('Colors'), instead of the actual color name, and the values of the dataframe are always 0. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Sorry, typo in `alias`. Should be OK now.